# How to cache mustache templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, caching, external, mustache

I would like to cache `mustache` templates.

I know that I could include `mustache` templates directly, like this:

```
<script id="mustache-template" type="text/html">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
</script>
```

And call those with javascript, like this:

```
var html, template, data;
data = {  
    title : "Some title"
}; 
template = document.getElementById('mustache-template').innerHTML;
html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
```

This won't cache templates. Only way I could figure out is usage of link -tags, but **how do I call template content via `javascript` without an `ajax` request?**

This won't work (of course)...

*HTML*

```
<link type="text/html" href="/mustache/template.tpl" id="mustache-template" />
```

*Javascript*

```
document.getElementById('mustache-template').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is very interesting! I had the same problem several months ago when I started to use mustache for 'huge' front-end templating within a rails project.

I ended up with the following solution...

---

Mustache templates are inside a public folder :

> ```
> /public/templates/_template_name.tpl
> ```

Whenever I need a template I have this helper *getTemplate* that does some stuff (there's some mootools, but there are comments too):

```
// namespace.templatesCache is an object ( {} ) defined inside the main app js file

var 
    needXHR = false, // for callback function
    templateHTML = ""; //template html

if(!(templateHTML = namespace.templatesCache[template_name])){ //if template is not cached

    templateHTML = (this.helpers.supportLocalStorage) ? localStorage.getItem(template_name) : ""; //if browser supports local storage, check if I can retrieve it

    if(templateHTML === "" || templateHTML === null){ // if I don't have a template (usually, first time), retrieve it by ajax

      needXHR = true;  

      new Request.HTML({ //or jQuery's $.get( url /*, etc */ ) 

          url: namespace.URLS.BASE+"templates/_"+template_name+".tpl", // url of the template file

          onSuccess : function(t, e, html, js){

                namespace.templatesCache[template_name] = html; //cache it

                if(_this.helpers.supportLocalStorage){ //and store it inside local storage, if available
                  localStorage.setItem(template_name,html); 
                }

                //call callback      
          }
      }).get();

    }else{ //retrieved by localStorage, let's cache it

        namespace.templatesCache[template_name] = templateHTML;

    }

}

if(!needXHR){ // I retrieved template by cache/localstorage, not by Ajax

    //call callback    

}
```

and I call this helper in this way :

```
namespace.helpers.getTemplate('template_name', function( templateHTML ){
    // the callback function
});
```

You can notice that first time user needs the template, there's an asynch request (you could make a sync request if u don't want to wrap some other code inside the callback)

I hope it could help and I'd love to receive feedbacks/suggestions concerning this stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to load your template in an `iframe` that contains an HTML page(that will be cached) with all your `script` tags inside.

Then you can read them from the main page, or push them from the iframe to the `parent` window.

That is what I do when using [pure.js](http://beebole.com/pure) templates

Comment: Thanks! Nice workaround, but this seems a little bit hacky to me. All other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I've made quite a few circles around this problem. Once you pass the trauma: `iframe` are something you shouldn't use, everything is fine. But I look forward for any other answer you will get.

Answer (score 1):

What you say it will not work, of course, because the innerHTML attribute of the liknek element will not give you the contents of the link.

You can use [Chevron](https://github.com/surdu/jquery-chevron) to load external templates from links like so:

You add in you template a link to your template file:

```
<link href="path/to/template.mustache" rel="template" id="templateName"/>
```

Then, in you JS you can render your template like so:

```
$("#templateName").Chevron("render", {name: "Slim Shady"}, function(result){
    // do something with 'result'
    // 'result' will contain the result of rendering the template
    // (in this case 'result' will contain: My name is Slim Shady)
});
```

The docs of Chevron will give more examples